# Parse JSON in RxJS

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

So, I'm very new to Angular and RxJS and I primarily come from a VueJS background. I'm currently having difficulties understanding how RxJS really works and would appreciate some more experienced input on my current predicament.

What I'm trying to do:
So I'm using the nomics API(see link below) to grab some data that is returned as an array of objects. Now, I completely understand how to simply display all of those objects on my component. But what if I wanted to select one specific object based on one of it's properties. For example, "go through every object in the array until I hit the object with object.Currency == 'BTC' ". All I currently have working is pulling all the data, which I can display. How would I further isolate the data based on some condition of one of the objects?

API Link: http://docs.nomics.com/#operation/getDashboard

My code:

```
getDashboard() {
return this.http.get(`${this.apiUrl}/dashboard?key=${this.apiKey}`).pipe(
  map(result => {
    console.log(result);
    // Do stuff here to isolate return obj to obj with specific property in Object.Currency
    // For example, keep going through objects until currentObject.Currency== 'Some string'
  })
)
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use filter() array operator

if it is an array of objects

```
 this.http.get(`${this.apiUrl}/dashboard?key=${this.apiKey}`).pipe(
      tap(console.log),
      map(arr=>arr.filter(obj => obj.Currency && obj.Currency == 'BTC' ))
    )
```

or

```
 this.http.get(`${this.apiUrl}/dashboard?key=${this.apiKey}`).pipe(
      tap(console.log),
      switchMap(arr=>from(arr)),
      filter(obj => obj.Currency && obj.Currency == 'BTC' ),
      toArray()
    )
```

Comment: I get the following error: Property 'currency' does not exist on type 'Object'. Would declaring an interface for the return type help here?

Comment: try add tap(console.log) operator right after http and check what properties obj has

Comment: It shows an array with about 657 objects, and an observable below the array response. I tried using the second option  you provided and it said that filter does not exist on object

Comment: edited the answer. To check if obj has such property - Currency. You can bascially debug according to what you log to the console, I think error is due to your result data structure.

Comment: Yeah I did debug and the obj definitely has a Currency property. I don't know why it would say otherwise

Comment: It says 'Property 'Currency' does not exist on type 'never''. Wow im not even sure what that type is...

Comment: I add the any type to the obj but then get an error saying Cannot find the name 'obj'

Comment: Ok so the issue was it was supposed to be Object.currency, not Currency. I'm so sorry for the waste of time. Thank you so much. I will research operators further

Answer (score 1):

You will need to apply the filter on your response like this:

```
  getDashboard() {
    return this.http.get(`${this.apiUrl}/dashboard?key=${this.apiKey}`).pipe(
      map(result => result.pipe(filter(currentObject => currentObject.Currency == 'Some string')))
    )
  }
```

But, I recommend you to do this filtering in your component where are you going to get the returned response and not in the service where you are making API call.